# Triggering custom touchpoint in Eclipse p2 after install action

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, p2

I successfully followed the steps of the [tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/05/23/custom-touchpoints-in-p2/) written by [Ian Bull](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/author/irbull/) on how to create custom touchpoints in p2.

As far as I know, there are only the phases *install*, *uninstall*, *configure* and *unconfigure*. However, I need to execute my custom touchpoint after I successfully installed the plugin which has my custom touchpoint specified as a MetaRequirement, not before. I tried to use the phase *configure*, but unfortunately, this did not work.

Are there more phases, for example *afterInstall*?

Answer (score 0):

The phases are basically defined by the installer.  The default phases are:

1. `collect` - collect/download the artifacts to be installed
2. `checkTrust` - check the certificates of downloaded artifacts to ensure they are trusted.
3. `unconfigure` - remove configuration data for things being uninstalled
4. `uninstall` - remove artifacts for things being uninstalled
5. `property` - perform changes to profile properties
6. `install` - install new things
7. `configure` - configure new things

The `configure` phase should be happening after the `install` phase.